# Error con hilos "Se tuvo acceso al control.."

Tags: c#

Estoy usando hilos para hacer que una imagen se desplace de un lado para otro y no se mueve ni un cm. Ya metí el mismo código a un `timer` y si hace lo que quiero, pero es necesario usar hilos y me da este error:

> Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control
>   'pictureBox1' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t = new Thread(movEne);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        t.Start();
        button1.Visible = false;
    }
    public void movEne()
    {
        if (!ene1)
        {
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + 5, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
            if (this.pictureBox1.Location.X >= this.Height)
            {
                ene1 = true;
            }
        } else
        {
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X - 5, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
            if (this.pictureBox1.Location.X <= 0)
            {
                ene1 = false;
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La excepción se dispara debido a que estas creando un nuevo thread, y este no puede modificar el UI, ya que el único que puede hacerlo es el UI Thread (el hilo principal en tu programa).

Para solucionar esta problemática, lo que debes hacer es usar [`Invoke(Delegate d)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2), lo podes hacer de la siguiente manera, por ejemplo:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + 5, pictureBox1.Location.Y)));
```

Sin embargo, siempre es bueno chequear si es requerido el uso de [`Invoke`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2), y caso contrario, llamarlo de modo normal, para hacerlo, debemos usar la propiedad [`InvokeRequired`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired?view=netframework-4.7.2), por ejemplo

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + 5, pictureBox1.Location.Y)));                
}
else
{ 
     this.pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + 5, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
}
```

Para más información te recomiendo la lectura de [este](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls) articulo de la página de Microsoft.

Comment: Gracias por la información me sirvió a la perfección